# Use Agent on other virtual machine TFS 2010

Tags: build, controller, agent

I have already a problem with my builds definition.
I explain :

1. i have 1 controller on my server
2. 1 default agent on this server
3. 1 default agent on a virtual machine.

When i build my project with the agent present on the server everythings good. But when i disable this agent and use the agent present on my virtual machine i have this problem :

**MSBUILD : error MSB4016: Arrêt inattendu de la génération, car le journal "WorkflowCentralLogger" a échoué de manière inattendue lors de l'initialisation. TF214007 : aucune build n'a été trouvée avec l'URI vstfs:///Build/Build/236. L'URI n'existe pas ou MS(nameofmachinevirtual)$ ne dispose pas des autorisations pour y accéder.**

**TF270015: 'MSBuild.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'.**

Sorry it's in french...

I use the administrator account for evitate some rights problems...

When i want to restart the build service present on my virtual machine i have this :

Communication failure between the Administration Console and the Build Service:

**The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://build/ServiceHost/8' could not be found on your local machine.  This is usually caused by the Build Service being in an incorrect state.**

If someone can help me because i block with that since 1 weeks...
Sorry for my english...

Best Regards Maxime SZAC.

Answer (score 0):

This might simply be a permissions issue:
Go to Team Explorer & right-click on the TeamProject where your Build Definition lives. Select "Team Project Settings" > "Group Membership...". You might want to add your VM in the `[TeamProject]\Builders` Group.
In order to do that double-click the Group, press "Add member" > "Windows User or Group" and then at "Object Types" select "Computer"
[image]

If you then enter (VM-Name)$, your VM should be findable.

Comment: removed the brackets and the dollar sign and get 

    Team Foundation Server could not resolve the user or group 'MYVM'. The user or group might be a member of a different domain, or the server might not have access to that domain. Verify the domain membership of the server and any domain trusts.

Which is a problem because IT say I can not have my VMs on the domain.

Comment: Tried with the second VM, Selected "Computers" and then set the location as "Entire network", typed in the name without brackets or dollar sign. Then on the next screen which showed the name underlined added a backslash and entered the local user to that VM and it accepted it.

Comment: This is not funny anymore. The computer was not accepted, just got no error message. Tried again and again and again. Cannot connect to VMs (though the machine names are verified).